# What are ClientUIFilterFlags (LineMarkers or MetaRefresh) in Azure AD B2C custom policies?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

When looking through examples for [Azure AD B2C Custom Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-overview), I often notice the `ClientUIFilterFlags` tag in the client definitions, [for example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/e4b6c895f6769344ed5868c74ee5db6762cf7e7f/conditional-access-preview/deprecated_B2CTenant.onmicrosoft.com-B2C_1A_PolicySampleV02.xml#L339):

```
<ClientDefinitions>
  <ClientDefinition Id="DefaultWeb">
    <ClientUIFilterFlags>LineMarkers, MetaRefresh</ClientUIFilterFlags>
  </ClientDefinition>
</ClientDefinitions>
```

I assume its purpose is to customize the UI, but I could not find any documentation. What does it mean? What is a LineMarker? What is MetaRefresh? Are there any other options?

The code snippet comes with Microsoft's official [starter kit](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack) (e.g., [in this example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/f7733e2eb316c468d49542fa8fbdc9b6eae9ee8c/SocialAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L254)), and everyone copies it.
It is probably a detail, but I am curious what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this tag is deprecated now. Here's an excerpt from the Azure AD B2C Custom Policies Deep Dive PDF:

> Client definitions specify various properties specific to the end-user
> device for which the policy is being executed. **These definitions
> should be considered deprecated.**
>
> To include the list of client
> definitions that can be used in the user journeys, a ClientDefinitions
> XML element must be declared under the BuildingBlocks section of the
> policy XML file. This element is optional.

[Source](https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/6/1/36187D50-A693-4547-848A-176F17AE1213/Deep%20Dive%20on%20Azure%20AD%20B2C%20Custom%20Policies/Azure%20AD%20B2C%20Custom%20Policies%20-%20Deep%20Dive%20on%20Custom%20Policy%20Schema.pdf)